# Why is my dynamic array always size 2 regardless of changing the value or user input?

Tags: c++

Hi guys I don't know why this is always giving me 2 as the size. I'm new to using dynamic arrays.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int x;
    int *arr = NULL;
    cout << "Enter size of array: ";
    cin >> x;
    arr = new int[x];

    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    cout << n << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`arr` is a pointer to `int`. `sizeof(arr)` will always return the size of a pointer (it is not dependant on the data pointed to), which, on your architecture, apparently is twice as big as `sizeof(int)`.

```
int * arr = nullptr;
size_t ptr_before_alloc = sizeof(arr);
arr = new int[1024];
size_t ptr_after_alloc = sizeof(arr);
assert(ptr_before_alloc == ptr_after_alloc); // this is guaranteed
```

If you want to pass your data allocated with `new[]` somewhere, you need to pass the size separately, or, better yet, use a container like [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) which will do this for you.

Comment: So then how do I make an array of dynamic size? I need it to be dynamic. Or is there a way to return arrays from within switch cases?

Comment: Then you need to return a pair of values: pointer and the size, there's no way around it.